# c# Iterate array of parent type to invoke non-polymorphic method on derived type

Tags: c#

I am using very similar loops to iterate all public fields and properties of any passed object. I determine if the field/property is decorated with a particular custom attribute; if so, an action is performed on the value of the field or property. Two loops are necessary because the method to get a field value is different from the method to get a property value.

```cs
// Iterate all public fields using reflection
foreach (FieldInfo fi in obj.GetType().GetFields())
{
  // Determine if decorated with MyAttribute.
  var attribs = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
  if (attribs.Length == 1)
  {
    // Get value of field.
    object value = fi.GetValue(obj);
    DoAction(value);
  }
}

// Iterate all public properties using reflection
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  // Determine if decorated with MyAttribute.
  var attribs = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
  if (attribs.Length == 1)
  {
    // Get value of property.
    object value = pi.GetValue(obj, null);
    DoAction(value);
  }
}
```

I would like to place the loop in a single, common method so that I can instead write, more simply:

```cs
DoEachMember(obj.GetType().GetFields());
DoEachMember(obj.GetType().GetProperties());
```

This requires `DoEachMember()` to accept the `MemberInfo` type (which is the parent type of both `FieldInfo` and `PropertyInfo`). The problem is there is no `GetValue` method in the `MemberInfo` class. Both `FieldInfo` and `PropertyInfo` use different methods to get the field/property value:

```cs
public void DoEachMember(MemberInfo mi, object obj)
{
  foreach (MemberInfo mi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    object value mi.GetValue(obj); // NO SUCH METHOD!
  }
}
```

Thus, I declare a delegate to utilize inside the loop which takes a `MemberInfo` and returns the value of that member as an object:

```cs
// Delegate to get value from field or property.
delegate object GetValue(MemberInfo mi, object obj);
```

### The Question

How can I detect the type of the objects in the `members[]` array, in order to define the delegate used inside the loop? Currently, I am using the first element of the array, `members[0]`. Is this a good design?

```cs
public void DoEachMember(MemberInfo[] members, object obj)
{
  // Protect against empty array.
  if (members.Length == 0) return;

  GetValue getValue; // define delegate

  // First element is FieldInfo
  if (members[0] as FieldInfo != null)
    getValue = (mi, obj) => ((FieldInfo)mi).GetValue(obj);

  // First element is PropertyInfo
  else if (members[0] as PropertyInfo != null)
    getValue = (mi, obj) => ((PropertyInfo)mi).GetValue(obj, null);

  // Anything else is unacceptable
  else
    throw new ArgumentException("Must be field or property.");

  foreach (MemberInfo mi in members)
  {
    // Determine if decorated with MyAttribute.
    var attribs = mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
    if (attribs.Length == 1)
    {
      object value = getValue(mi, obj);
      DoStuff(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I could detect the type upon each iteration, but there *should* be no reason individual array members will ever differ:

```cs
foreach (MemberInfo mi in members)
{
  // ...

  object value;

  if ((var fi = mi as FieldInfo) != null)
    value = fi.GetValue(obj);

  else if ((var pi = mi as PropertyInfo) != null)
    value = pi.GetValue(obj, null);

  else
    throw new ArgumentException("Must be field or property.");

  DoStuff(value);
}
```

Comment: Don't do this; `if(o as SomeType != null) var s = (SomeType)o;`.  You are performing two casts when only one is required and adding useless verbosity to your code.  Simply use; `var s = o as SomeType; if(s != null) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Heckuva good question, @kevin-p-rice !!

Comment: @EdS. +1. Though, in my primary solution the `as` only occurs once to determine the proper delegate for each iteration. In my alternate solution your advice applies, but it destroys the if/elseif/else structure. But I could do both assignment and test inside the if expression: `if ((s = mi as FieldInfo) != null) {} else if ((s = mi as PropertyInfo) != null) {} ...`

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Gee, thanks. How could I not +1 that too? :)

Comment: Well, yes, how could you not, @kevin-p-rice! Doesn't give me rep points, but whatever.  I am surprised @jon-skeet hasn't weighed in on this one -- seems right up his alley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could project to the object values first and then work on those in your loop.  Your whole code could be boiled down to this (plus your loop):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of all the fields or properties on an object that are decorated with the specified attribute
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerable<object> GetValuesFromAttributedMembers<TAttribute>(object obj)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var values1 = obj.GetType().GetFields()
                        .Where(fi => fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).Any())
                        .Select(fi => fi.GetValue(obj));
        var values2 = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).Any())
                        .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(obj, null));
        return values1.Concat(values2);
    }
```

Your current code mixes two concerns: finding the values and doing something with them.  It would be cleaner to separate those concerns.  The above LINQ could be placed in one method that fetches all values from a class that are in fields or properties that match a given attribute and another than is just a loop doing the work on whatever it is passed.

Not as clean but sticking with your original goal you could do this and pass in a delegate appropriate to the type of the MemberInfo you are retrieving:-

```
    public void DoEachMember<TAttribute, TMembertype>(IEnumerable<TMembertype> members,
                             Func<TMembertype, object> valueGetter)
        where TMembertype : MemberInfo
    {
        foreach (var mi in members)
        {
            if (mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).Any())
            {
                // Get value of field.
                object value = valueGetter(mi);
                DoAction(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very nice, indeed. I *ESPECIALLY* appreciate your very valid observation about SoC. I always hesitate to utilize LINQ because it is a big hammer for a simple looping problem. LINQ hides a ton of complexity (in many cases) and I am very careful to try to recognize that before using LINQ because it looks cleaner. I lean towards LINQ for larger operations where deferred execution is valuable, and lean towards C-like code for low level stuff. In this case, your insight on SoC speaks largely to the answer sought. Much thanks.

Comment: Your generic method (edit #3) is very sweet. I do think the delegate should be determined by the method, not passed, as it is one or the other. One issue with your first LINQ example is I didn't disclose that `DoAction` needs the attribute instance and the value. If the attribute exists it is in element zero and I use it something like this: `DoAction(value, attribs[0])`. Your LINQ example would require some rework to include both in the Select, plus I see no cause to Concat the two results over calling `DoEachMember` twice (just extra object acrobatics going on there).

Answer (score 1):

You should use generics:

```
public void DoEachMember<T>(T[] members, object obj) where T: MemberInfo
{
}
```

Inside, test what T is, and decide which method to call based on that:

```
if(typeof(T)==PropertyInfo.GetType()) ...
```

You can obviously do the check just once, and not every iteration.

Comment: I am liking this a lot. The object passed is either a `FieldInfo[]` or `PropertyInfo[]`. Generics appears to to allow both passing the derived type itself instead of a parent type array AND ensures the entire array is homogeneous. Yes, I am liking this answer...

Comment: Good. Just remember that inside you still have to take both cases into account. I wouldn't use delegates here, it'll make the code a little harder to read - because all you have is two cases.

Answer (score 1):

I approached this by wrapping MemberInfo in an interface like so:

```
public interface IMemberInfo
{
    MemberInfo Wrapped { get; }

    object GetValue( object obj );

    void SetValue( object obj, object value );
}

internal abstract class MemberInfoWrapper : IMemberInfo
{
    protected readonly MemberInfo MemberInfo;

    public MemberInfoWrapper( MemberInfo memberInfo )
    {
        MemberInfo = memberInfo;
    }

    public abstract object GetValue( object obj );

    public abstract void SetValue( object obj, object value );

    public virtual MemberInfo Wrapped
    {
        get { return MemberInfo; }
    }
}

internal class PropertyInfoWrapper : MemberInfoWrapper
{
    public PropertyInfoWrapper( MemberInfo propertyInfo ) : base( propertyInfo )
    {
        Debug.Assert( propertyInfo is PropertyInfo );
    }

    public override object GetValue( object obj )
    {
        return ( (PropertyInfo)MemberInfo ).GetValue( obj, null );
    }

    public override void SetValue( object obj, object value )
    {
        ( (PropertyInfo)MemberInfo ).SetValue( obj, value, null );
    }
}

internal class FieldInfoWrapper : MemberInfoWrapper
{
    public FieldInfoWrapper( MemberInfo fieldInfo ) : base( fieldInfo )
    {
        Debug.Assert( fieldInfo is FieldInfo );
    }

    public override object GetValue( object obj )
    {
        return ( (FieldInfo)MemberInfo ).GetValue( obj );
    }

    public override void SetValue( object obj, object value )
    {
        ( (FieldInfo)MemberInfo ).SetValue( obj, value );
    }
}
```

And a factory:

```
internal static class MemberInfoWrapperFactory
{
    public static IMemberInfo CreateWrapper( this MemberInfo memberInfo )
    {
        switch ( memberInfo.MemberType )
        {
            case MemberTypes.Property:
                return new PropertyInfoWrapper( memberInfo );
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                return new FieldInfoWrapper( memberInfo );
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Given this, you can, in your method:

```
// Iterate all public members using reflection
foreach (MemberInfo mi in obj.GetType().GetMembers().Where(x => x is PropertyInfo || x is FieldInfo))
{
  // Determine if decorated with MyAttribute.
  var attribs = mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
  if (attribs.Length == 1)
  {
    // Get value of property.
    object value = mi.CreateWrapper().GetValue(obj, null);
    DoAction(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Another elegant solution! The only code I don't like here is `GetMembers().Where(x => x is PropertyInfo || x is FieldInfo)` because it gets many more members than necessary, then attempts two separate casts for each to narrow that back down. I do not mind calling the loop twice (once each for fields/properties) to prevent that. But your wrapper is good stuff, man!

Comment: I agree with you, this example comes from something much more complicated, and I sort of added that Where() at the last minute as I was typing this up.  There are plenty of better ways to do it, I'm sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var areProperties = members.All(m => m is PropertyInfo);
var areFields = members.All(m => m is FieldInfo);
```

`areProperties` will be true only if all items in the `members[]` array are PropertyInfo objects.

Comment: Thx. The question--or hesitation, might be more accurate--is not so much ensuring the homogeneity of the array (which your code addresses), but whether the general approach in utilizing a common loop is best practice.

Comment: It's good practice if people can understand what it does. It's a fairly simple common loop, so *in this case* it seems like good practice.

Comment: @zmbq Yes, defensive programming is good practice. However, your answer using generics makes testing each element of the entire array unnecessary--which is even better practice!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, if you're using `C# 4.0`

```
public void DoEachMember(MemberInfo[] members, object obj)
{
   var properties = new List<dynamic>(); //dynamic objects list 
   properties.AddRange(members) ; // add all members to list of dynamics    
   foreach(dynamic d in porperties) //iterate over collection 
   {
      var attribs = d.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true); //call dynamicaly
      if (attribs.Length == 1)
      {
         // Get value of property.
         object value = d.GetValue(obj, null); //call dynamically
         DoAction(value);
      }
   }
 }
```

Code becomes very short and straightforward.
*Should* work.

Good luck